# Shibboleth - certificate name was not acceptable

Tags: single-sign-on, shibboleth

I am using my SP to authenticate with TestShib IDP. After logging in on the IDP, on the SP Side I get this error

```
Unable to establish security of incoming assertion.
```

From the shibd.log I see

```
2016-11-03 11:30:34 ERROR XMLTooling.TrustEngine.PKIX [4]: certificate name was not acceptable
2016-11-03 11:30:34 ERROR OpenSAML.SecurityPolicyRule.XMLSigning [4]: unable to verify message signature with supplied trust engine
2016-11-03 11:30:34 WARN Shibboleth.SSO.SAML2 [4]: detected a problem with assertion: Unable to establish security of incoming assertion.
```

Please advise.

Update-

More from shibd.log

```
2016-11-03 11:10:55 INFO Shibboleth.AttributeExtractor.XML : creating mapping for Attribute urn:oid:2.5.4.3
2016-11-03 11:10:55 INFO Shibboleth.AttributeExtractor.XML : creating mapping for Attribute urn:oid:2.5.4.4
2016-11-03 11:10:55 INFO Shibboleth.Application : building AttributeFilter of type XML...
 2016-11-03 11:10:55 INFO Shibboleth.AttributeFilter : reload thread started...running when signaled
 2016-11-03 11:10:55 INFO Shibboleth.AttributeFilter : loaded XML resource (/opt/shibboleth-sp/etc/shibboleth/attribute-policy.xml)     
2016-11-03 11:10:55 INFO Shibboleth.Application : building AttributeResolver of type Query...
2016-11-03 11:10:55 INFO Shibboleth.Application : building CredentialResolver of type File...
2016-11-03 11:10:55 INFO XMLTooling.SecurityHelper : loading private key from file (/opt/shibboleth-sp/etc/shibboleth/sp-key.pem)
2016-11-03 11:10:55 INFO XMLTooling.SecurityHelper : loading certificate(s) from file (/opt/shibboleth-sp/etc/shibboleth/sp-cert.pem)
2016-11-03 11:10:55 INFO Shibboleth.Listener : registered remoted message endpoint (default::getHeaders::Application)
2016-11-03 11:10:55 INFO Shibboleth.Listener : listener service starting
2016-11-03 11:11:34 ERROR XMLTooling.TrustEngine.PKIX [2]: certificate name was not acceptable
2016-11-03 11:11:34 ERROR OpenSAML.SecurityPolicyRule.XMLSigning [2]: unable to verify message signature with supplied trust engine
2016-11-03 11:11:34 WARN Shibboleth.SSO.SAML2 [2]: detected a problem with assertion: Unable to establish security of incoming assertion.
2016-11-03 11:25:55 INFO XMLTooling.StorageService : purged 3 expired record(s) from storage
2016-11-03 11:30:34 ERROR XMLTooling.TrustEngine.PKIX [4]: certificate name was not acceptable
2016-11-03 11:30:34 ERROR OpenSAML.SecurityPolicyRule.XMLSigning [4]: unable to verify message signature with supplied trust engine
2016-11-03 11:30:34 WARN Shibboleth.SSO.SAML2 [4]: detected a problem with assertion: Unable to establish security of incoming assertion.
2016-11-03 11:40:55 INFO XMLTooling.StorageService : purged 3 expired record(s) from storage
```

From shibd_warn.log

```
2016-11-03 10:50:10 WARN Shibboleth.SSO.SAML2 [2]: detected a problem with assertion: Message was signed, but signature could not be verified.
2016-11-03 11:11:34 ERROR XMLTooling.TrustEngine.PKIX [2]: certificate name was not acceptable
2016-11-03 11:11:34 ERROR OpenSAML.SecurityPolicyRule.XMLSigning [2]: unable to verify message signature with supplied trust engine
2016-11-03 11:11:34 WARN Shibboleth.SSO.SAML2 [2]: detected a problem with assertion: Unable to establish security of incoming assertion.
2016-11-03 11:30:34 ERROR XMLTooling.TrustEngine.PKIX [4]: certificate name was not acceptable
2016-11-03 11:30:34 ERROR OpenSAML.SecurityPolicyRule.XMLSigning [4]: unable to verify message signature with supplied trust engine
2016-11-03 11:30:34 WARN Shibboleth.SSO.SAML2 [4]: detected a problem with assertion: Unable to establish security of incoming assertion.
```

Comment: Where did you provided certificate name?

Comment: @Akshay certificate name is provided in the shibboleth2.xml

Answer (score 0):

You should **NOT** use PKIX, but explicit Trust.

The error happens when your SP tries to verify the signature ( thus the authenticity ) of the SAML Assertion that comes from the testshib IDP. You have configured your SP to validate signatures using the [PKIX TrustEngine](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/PKIXTrustEngine) and the  does not match any of the

- subject DN in reverse/LDAP comma-separated syntax, with or without spaces (see RFC 2253)
- subject CN
- any DNS and URL subjectAltNames

of your certificate.

Using an [ExplicitKey TrustEngine](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/ExplicitKeyTrustEngine) is much simpler and the recommended approach. That would mean that the SP will get to know about the signing certificate of the TestShib IdP from the metadata directly.

Comment: How do i switch from PKIX to Explicit Trust Engine ? Where do I make this change ?

Comment: If you haven't changed it yourself, you use the default configuration which means that you have a chained trust engine, first explicit and the PKIX. Since it reaches the PKIX and fails I assume that it can't match the certificate of the idp in the metadata. You will have to show us relevant entries from your shibd/ shibd_warn logs before the ones you already shared

Comment: I added  <TrustEngine type="ExplicitKey"> in shibboleth2.xml and I get this error.
2016-11-04 14:29:58 ERROR OpenSAML.SecurityPolicyRule.XMLSigning [2]: unable to verify message signature with supplied trust engine

Comment: it could be that the SP can't read the key from the metadata file.  I assume you have followed the examples from testshib and have a Metadataprovider that loads the testshib metadata xml in your Shibboleth2.xml?

Comment: Also this old message http://shibboleth.1660669.n2.nabble.com/Failure-to-validate-Response-Signature-td7582247i20.html describes a very similar problem so please check the xml namespaces in the idp and sp metadata

Comment: as per example my xml tags follows this high level structure
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:KeyName></ds:KeyName>
<dsX509Data>
<ds:X509SubjectName></ds:X509SubjectName>
<ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509>
   </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>